# Distributing teams into units

Tags: recursion

Really struggling to solve this problem correctly.

my solution, that correctly solves some of the test cases is [here:](https://repl.it/@mrcmcalpine/House-Solution)

Really hoping that someone can help me understand what's missing, or point me to solutions that I can learn from

Problem Description:

administration is considering to house each team in several units with at least 5 people per unit. A team can have from 5 to 100 members, depending on the sport they do. For example, if there are 16 team members, there are 6 ways to distribute the team members into units: (1) one unit with 16 team members; (2) two units with 5 and 11 team members, respectively; (3) two units with 6 and 10 team members, respectively; (4) two units with 7 and 9 team members, respectively; (5) two units with 8 team members each; (6) two units with 5 team members each plus a third unit with 6 team members. This list might become quite lengthy for a large team size.

In order to see how many choices to distribute the team members there are, the administration would like to have a computer program that computes for a number n the number m(n) of possible ways to distribute the team members into the units allocated, with at least 5 people per unit. Note that equivalent distributions like 5 + 5 + 6, 5 + 6 + 5 and 6 + 5 + 5 are counted only once. So m(16) = 6 (as seen above), m(17) = 7 (namely 17, 5 + 12, 6 + 11, 7 + 10, 8 + 9, 5 + 5 + 7, 5 + 6 + 6) and m(20) = 13.

The computer program should read the number n and compute m(n).

Answer (score 1):

The recursion is pretty simple:  We can count the partitions of `n` items that include the lower bound, and those that don't, and add them together.  If we include the lower bound (`lb`), then there are `n - lb` more items to place, and our lower bound hasn't changed.  If we're not including it, then there are still `n` items to place, but our `lb` has increased.  Our base cases are simple:  when the lower bound is higher than the number of items, there are no partitions.  When they're equal, there is one.  This code should do it:

```py
def count (n, lb):
  if (lb > n):
    return 0
  if (lb == n):
    return 1
  return count (n - lb, lb) + count (n, lb + 1)

count (20, 5) #=> 13
```

If you want to test different values, you can use a JS version of this:

```js
const count = (n, lb) =>
  lb > n
    ? 0
  : lb == n
    ? 1
  : count (n - lb, lb) + count (n, lb + 1)
    

console .log (count (20, 5))
```

And if you want to see the actual values instead of the counts, you can run this variant:

```js
const count = (n, lb) =>
  lb > n
    ? []
  : lb == n
    ? [[n]]
  : [
      ... count (n - lb, lb) .map (r => [lb, ...r]),
      ... count (n , lb + 1)
    ]

console .log (count (17, 5))
```